# Power BI - Couldn't load model schema

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-powerbi

I installed Power BI Desktop (win 10 / Product Version: 2.56.5023.1021). The first session was okay, but since the second one, I get the error message *"Couldn't load model schema"* every time, when I want to open an existed .pbix file. I reinstalled the software several times, but the problem is the same every time. I use the latest release of Power BI. I'm not sure if it is a relevant info but I'm using SQL Server Express 2017 without SSAS.

How could I fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the same issue as reported here:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Not-able-to-open-PBI-file-even-new-blank-one/idi-p/377743

The solution posted by Microsoft on https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/support/ is:

> Users can work around this issue by running the following command from
>   an elevated command prompt: "C:\Program Files\Windows
>   Defender\MpCmdRun.exe –resetplatform"

Presumably this is some clash with Windows Defender.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot. By the way it doesn't work for me. The problem is still there

Comment: @CsabaCsorba I have been facing the same issue. Did you find a workaround for it ? I tried running the windows defender -resetplatform option but it threw me a error saying its an invalid option

Comment: @Rima Sorry, I haven't been around for a while. Actually, yes there was an update which solved the problem. On the web I didn't find any useful answer.